# What is the difference between glGenRenderbuffers and glCreateRenderbuffers?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, glfw, glm-math

SPEC:

> 1. glCreateRenderbuffers:
>    glCreateRenderbuffers — create renderbuffer objects
>
> void glCreateRenderbuffers(GLsizei n, GLuint *renderbuffers);
>
> n: Number of renderbuffer objects to create.
> renderbuffers: Specifies an array in which names of the new renderbuffer objects are stored.
>
> glCreateRenderbuffers returns n previously unused renderbuffer object names in renderbuffers, each representing a new renderbuffer object initialized to the default state.
>
> 2. glGenRenderbuffers — generate renderbuffer object names
>    void glGenRenderbuffers(GLsizei n, GLuint *renderbuffers);
>
> n: Specifies the number of renderbuffer object names to generate.
> renderbuffers: Specifies an array in which the generated renderbuffer object names are stored.
>
> glGenRenderbuffers returns n renderbuffer object names in renderbuffers. There is no guarantee that the names form a contiguous set of integers; however, it is guaranteed that none of the returned names was in use immediately before the call to glGenRenderbuffers.
>
> Renderbuffer object names returned by a call to glGenRenderbuffers are not returned by subsequent calls, unless they are first deleted with glDeleteRenderbuffers.
>
> The names returned in renderbuffers are marked as used, for the purposes of glGenRenderbuffers only, but they acquire state and type only when they are first bound.

so what is the difference between them?

I've tried to use `glCreateRenderbuffers` to replace `glGenRenderbuffers` in learn OpenGL tutorial https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Framebuffers but it reports an error.

Comment: What "reports an error"? What error does it report, and what does the spec say might cause that error when calling that function? Also, it's a good idea to use quoting syntax in Markdown when making a quote, so that we can tell the difference between your text and what you've quoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glGenRenderbuffers` is part of the established OpenGL API available since v3. This function only generates object handles ("names"). They become reserved so other OpenGL functions producing object names won't use them until generated handles are destroyed via call to `glDeleteRenderbuffers`. But otherwise these handles are not actually associated with backing object until they are bound to pipeline via call to `glBindRenderbuffer` for the first time and pretty much useless until that point.

In contrast `glCreateRenderbuffers` is part of [Direct State Access](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Direct_State_Access) extension and also available in the later versions of OpenGL API since v4.5 (so it will cause an error if you are using older API without extension). The core idea of this extension was to reduce need for indirect access to object that is currently bound to pipeline. Functions from this extension accept object handles so only a single call is required instead of going through bind object -> do something -> unbind object sequence. `glCreateRenderbuffers` not only generates object names, but also creates backing objects without any additional calls so produced object handles can be immediately used.

A good introduction into DSA extension as part of OpenGL 4.5 could be found in [Nvidia GTC presentation](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/siggraph/2014/presentation/SG4121-OpenGL-Update-NVIDIA-GPUs.pdf).

Comment: I think learnopengl tutorials use OpenGL 3.3 so `glCreateRenderbuffers` is missing.